# s3 image is not being rendering on any iPhone, working fine on web and Android

Tags: ios, angular, amazon-s3

I have an angular application where I am uploading the image to Amazon s3 bucket and get uploaded image URL(location) in the success response.
The image is perfectly rendering on all devices but not on the iPhone.

**CASE 1:**
If I upload the image from iPhone it works for:

- all of the devices(Web, Mobile, everywhere)

**CASE 2:**
If I upload the image from any device except iPhone, it works for:

- all of the devices(Web, Mobile), but not for iPhone

I have tried all access permissions on the bucket

```
this.bucket.upload(this.uploadParams, function (err, data) {
          if (data) {
            that.notasForm.controls['image'].setValue(data.Location);
          } else {
            that.clearImage();
          }
});
```

Comment: Is it possible to compare the headers from the different upload requests?

Comment: Well, really not as I am not able to get headers sent from iPhone browser.
Can we try any another way?

Comment: The other way is to check the properties of the S3 object in the AWS console. See if there is any difference in the properties when uploaded from iPhone.

Comment: The two objects' properties are ditto the same.

Comment: What image format are you using?

Comment: Also, "this.bucket.upload" is that an angular-specific AWS package?

Comment: I am using .PNG foramat

Comment: The package I am using is 
https://www.npmjs.com/package/aws-sdk

Comment: When the data is returned, what is the format of the S3 url for the image?

Comment: S3 Url is a property namely Location inside data object and as follow:

Location: "https://reciepepictures.s3.us-west-1.amazonaws.com/15732163057881573216305685.lJ3DW.png"

Comment: https://reciepepictures.s3.us-west-1.amazonaws.com/15732163057881573216305685.lJ3DW.png

If you open this link in iphone, it will not work and if you will open outside to iphone it will work like a charm

Comment: OK. Try this on the iphone instead: https://s3.us-west-1.amazonaws.com/reciepepictures/15732163057881573216305685.lJ3DW.png

Comment: That's the object address rather than the end point url

Comment: The new link isn't working as well

Comment: OK. I'm running out of ideas. Maybe try putObject instead, the advantage being that you know the url, it's the same for upload and download and do not have to wait for the response to setValue? https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/S3.html#putObject-property

Comment: My guess is that the iphone is blocking resources being downloaded from your S3 site somehow. If you have an app, then can't you whitelist urls? I don't have enough experience of iphone development to help you here.

Comment: Another reason to switch to Android :P